# Getting penultimate element in a Jinja2 iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2

Let `lst` be a `List`of vegetables represented as strings: `["cucumbers", "peppers", "tomatoes", "carrots"]`. I wish to join these with commas, except that I wish the last to be the word `and` instead (for the purpose of this exercise, let's assume a degree tolerance for the Oxford comma), to get the following:

`cucumbers, peppers, tomatoes, and carrots`

How would I go about accomplishing this in `Jinja2`? I know `loop.last` lets me identify the last, but not the penultimate iteration, which is where this would be relevant.

Comment: Why not process the list in plain python and make this easier

Comment: If you just need to put the word "and" in there, then why not just use `loop.last`?  Put the "and" in front of the word instead of after the word.

Answer (score 1):

```
{% if loop.revindex == 2 %}
```

Or

```
{% if loop.revindex0 == 1 %}
```

See for-loop variables in the [List of Control Structures](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#list-of-control-structures) chapter.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved the oxford comma by doing this:

```
{% for label in post.labels %}
    <li><a href="/labels/{{label}}">{{label}}</a>
    {% if not loop.last and loop.length > 2%}, {%endif%}
    {% if loop.revindex0 == 1 %} and{%endif%}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who don't want the Oxford comma, I've used this:

```
{% for name in my_list %}
  {{ name }}
  {%- if loop.length > 1 and not loop.last -%}
    {%- if loop.revindex0 == 1 %} and {% else %}, {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Outputs something like:

```
cucumbers, peppers, tomatoes and carrots
```